# パラメーターの表記法について

Tags: python, python3

`:` は記法の一つで、与えられるデータタイプを意味していると分かりましたが、
一番右の `-> List[int]` の意味が分かりません。

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

戻り値の型を表しています。intのListで返るということですね。

[typing --- 型ヒントのサポート](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/typing.html)

> バージョン 3.5 で追加.
> 以下の関数は文字列を受け取って文字列を返す関数で、次のようにアノテーションがつけられます:
>
> ```
> def greeting(name: str) -> str:
>     return 'Hello ' + name
> ```
>
> 関数 greeting で、実引数 name の型は str であり、返り値の型は str であることが期待されます。サブタイプも実引数として許容されます。

Comment: 初めてみて驚きましたが、そういうことだったのですね。なかなかみる機会もなく記号だとgoogleで出てこなかったので助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

関数の戻り値に対する型ヒントとなります
詳細は下記のリンクを参照してください。

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#return-values